# HTML/CSS - Background image not showing up in browser

Tags: html, css, image, background

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong here and can't seem to find a solution. The path is right and the image is in the right folder. Here is the code:

```
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>COSMOSHOP</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>


</html>
```

and the CSS code:

```
body {
    background-image: url('images/nightsky.jpg');
}
```

Comment: can I get a URL to see the actual page? It`s possible that the code isn't finding the path of the file.

Comment: have you tried just going to the location of the image in the browser and seeing what shows up?

Comment: If body is empty you can't see it's background because height is 0, try adding height to body or some content.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the dev console in the browser and check if the url is correct. it is very common at times it is not

Comment: this is not an answer

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the problem with HTML/CSS is the cache in your browser.
Try pressing ctrl + shift + delete, and remove browser cache.
See if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code provided, you have no `<body>` content. So you're body is essentially 0 pixels high. Try adding this and you should see your background image (assuming your paths are correct). Note, I'm only adding a height to the body so you can see that the image is there. Once you start building an actual site (i.e. content in your `<body>`), you can remove the height. As specifying a height property on your body tag is bad practice.

```
body {
    background-image: url('images/nightsky.jpg');
    height: 600px; // remove this once you start adding content to the body
}
```